# Is a main clause containing subordination canonical or non-canonical?

Tags: grammar, subordinate-clauses

According to Huddleston and Pullum's *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar*, canonical clauses are:

> those which are syntactically the most basic or elementary.

They mark subordinate clauses, such as *I know **that she's ill***, as non-canonical, while main clauses, such as *She's ill*, as canonical.

However, they don't say anything about main clauses containing embedded subordinate clauses. So, in the the previously mentioned example *I know that she's ill*, what is the type of the whole clause/sentence?

One might say that it is clearly canonical, since it is a main clause after all.  But, isn't it more complicated by virtue of having subordinate embedded element?

Comment: As @Edwin suggests, perhaps this is not a term you need to worry about. Literally, _canonical_ means 'specified by canons', where canons are comprehensive rules, like religions. Nothing in English grammar is canonical; that's one reason why the term hasn't caught on, like many other terminological innovations of CGEL.  Main clauses usually contain subordinate clauses; most sentences are complex. But the main or matrix clause is the one at the top level, which governs all the others.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The term has 14 entries in the index, and is dealt with quite comprehensively by CGEL.

Comment: What @JohnLawler said. In the cited context, ***canonical*** simply means "of a type which is *specifically* described" (in whatever "standard teaching materials" / textbooks are currently contextually relevant). But there will be different schools of thought with different ideas about what should or shouldn't be included in "the canons", so it's basically a subjective distinction.

Comment: The term is not an innovation of CGEL, as these references to it by UCL and Wiki show: [link](http://enwiki.org/w/Sentence_types) / [link](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/function/extra.htm) / [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topicalization). There are others. It's a fairly standard and useful term for describing certain basic, or elementary clauses. I use it quite regularly when talking of clause types. I'm not aware of any "different schools of thought" about what constitutes a canonical clause.

Comment: @BillJ Apologies (to all). I obviously need the large print edition (and a new house). The corresponding traditional terminology seems (at first glance) to be 'simple declarative sentence', with simple interrogatives etc and more involved sentences 'non-canonical'.